# Decode Json Data using JsonDecoder and Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, jsondecoder

I am trying decode Json data into my Model.
This is my model

```
struct Devices : Codable {
var id :String?
var description :String?
var status : Int?
```

}

```
 var heroes = Devices()
    print(DeviceId)
    let loginParam: [String: Any] = [
        "id": DeviceId
    ]
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    manager.request("http://13.13.13.004/website/api/Customer/DeviceControl", method: .post , parameters: loginParam, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted)
        .responseData { response in
            let json = response.data

            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                //using the array to put values
                heroes = try decoder.decode(Devices.self, from: json!)

            }catch let err{
                print(err)
            }
```

this code doesn't get in catch block.
But heroes values return nill.
When ı try use **NsDictionary** 
Its give result.

Comment: Could you do: `let jsonString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8); print("JSON: \(jsonString)` and give us what's the output?

Comment: @Larme its give correct result `JSON: Optional("{\"resultCount\":1,\"results\":[{\"id\":\"haktaneb\",\"status\":0,\"description\":\"asfasf\"}]}")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common mistake: You forget the root object

```
struct Root : Decodable {

    private enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case resultCount, devices = "results" }

    let resultCount : Int
    let devices : [Device]
}
```

And name the device struct in singular form (`devices` is an array of `Device` instances) and declare the members as non-optional

```
struct Device : Decodable {
    var id : String
    var description : String
    var status : Int
}

...

var heroes = [Device]()

...

let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: json!)
heroes = result.devices
```

Comment: Getting this error `typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: The code in the answer corresponds exactly to the JSON in the comment. The error says you want to decode `let results : Device` (without brackets).