# Can API not understand my property types?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, alamofire

I do not know how to explain ... but there is a feeling that the API knows how to set the string in the name, but it does not know how to enter properties with the structure type and set other values already

There is url for my API = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/akabab/superhero-api/0.2.0/api/all.json"

So I created the correct model that takes the values that I need. But for some reason, when I print my constant, it shows me that properties are missing, except for the name.

Here is my model:

```
struct SuperHero: Decodable {

    let name: String?
    let powerstats: PowerStats?
    let appearance: Appearance?
    let biography: Biography?
    let work: Work?
    let images: Images?
}

struct PowerStats: Decodable {

    let intelligence: Int
    let strength: Int
    let speed: Int
    let durability: Int
    let power: Int
    let combat: Int
}

struct Appearance: Codable {

    let gender: Gender
    let race: String?
    let height, weight: [String]
}

enum Gender: String, Codable {

    case empty = "-"
    case female = "Female"
    case male = "Male"
}

struct Biography: Codable {

    let fullName, alterEgos: String
    let aliases: [String]
    let firstAppearance: String
    let publisher: String?
    let alignment: Alignment
}

enum Alignment: String, Codable {

    case bad = "bad"
    case empty = "-"
    case good = "good"
    case neutral = "neutral"
}

struct Work: Codable {

    let occupation, base: String
}

struct Images: Decodable {

    let xs: String
    let sm: String
    let md: String
    let lg: String
}
```

And i try to fecth data by my function:

```
func fetchData() {

        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

        request(url).validate().responseJSON { (dataResponse) in

            switch dataResponse.result {

            case .success(let value):

                guard let arrayOfItems = value as? Array<[String : Any]> else { return }

                for dict in arrayOfItems {
                    let superHero = SuperHero(name: dict["name"] as? String,
                                              powerstats: dict["powerstats"] as? PowerStats,
                                              appearance: dict["appearance"] as? Appearance,
                                              biography: dict["biography"] as? Biography,
                                              work: dict["work"] as? Work,
                                              images: dict["images"] as? Images)

                    self.superHeroes.append(superHero)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }

            case.failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's like doing, because `dict` can contains only Array, Dictionary, String, Int objects, not custom ones. Instead of retrieved the already parse JSON (`value`), use the `Data` representation one that should be available in Alamofire.

Comment: @Larme Can you help and explain in more detail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110124/decode-json-data-using-jsondecoder-and-alamofire

Comment: This does not solve my problem.

Comment: You cannot map a custom object directly with just a reference to the dictionary. Write a init function for PowerStats, Appearance, biography etc...

Comment: Declare everything as non-optional to get errors. And why don't you use `JSONDecoder`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode Json Data using JsonDecoder and Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110124/decode-json-data-using-jsondecoder-and-alamofire)

Comment: @vadian i don't use JSONDecoder because my homework is work with Alamofire

Comment: You can use `JSONDecoder` also with Alamofire. Please see my answer.

Comment: "i don't use JSONDecoder because my homework is work with Alamofire " Why use Codable then? Alamofire can work with Codable and JSONDecoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you cannot cast a deserialized JSON dictionary value to a custom struct. You would have to create the other structs by calling their `init` methods like `SuperHero`.

As your structs conform to `Decodable` anyway use `JSONDecoder`, just replace `responseJSON` with `responseData` to get the raw data.

You can declare all members in the root struct as non-optional

```
struct SuperHero: Decodable {

    let name: String
    let powerstats: PowerStats
    let appearance: Appearance
    let biography: Biography
    let work: Work
    let images: Images
}
```

and all members in `Images` can directly be decoded to URL

```
struct Images: Decodable {        
    let xs: URL
    let sm: URL
    let md: URL
    let lg: URL
}
```

---

```
func fetchData() {

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

    request(url).validate().responseData { (dataResponse) in

        switch dataResponse.result {

        case .success(let data):

            do {
                self.superHeroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([SuperHero].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch { print(error) }

        case.failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

   }
}
```

To create the child structs in code you have to create each single instance. This is an exemple for `PowerStats`

```
for dict in arrayOfItems {
    let pwstats = dict["powerstats"] as! [String:Int]
    let powerStat = PowerStats(intelligence: pwstats["intelligence"]!,
                               strength: pwstats["strength"]!,
                               speed: pwstats["speed"]!,
                               durability: pwstats["durability"]!,
                               power: pwstats["power"]!,
                               combat: pwstats["combat"]!)

    let superHero = SuperHero(name: dict["name"] as? String,
                              powerstats: powerStat, ...
```

Be aware that most of the dictionaries are `[String:Any]` which requires an additional type cast for each value.

Comment: Yes, i know about this way, but condition of homework is another! 
But thanks anyway!

Comment: Then – as mentioned in the answer – you have to create all struct instances *manually*. That's a bunch of work.

Comment: Yes... unfortunately i know it. But how to do it? Can you show me on the example of powerstats?

Comment: Your answer is working! But the further, the more difficult it is to provide additional type conversions for each value.

Comment: It's just the same as in the line `dict["name"] as? String`

Comment: I'm getting angry! This is the worst job in the world, and most importantly it is not clear why! Can you help me finish it? At least with the cast of all types?
I will be very, very grateful !!!

Comment: Please read the JSON. There are only 2 collection types, array`[]` → `[[String:Any]]` and sometimes `[String]` and dictionary `{}` → `[String:Any]`, and there are 4 value types: Everything in double quotes is `String`, numeric integer values  are `Int`, floating point values are `Double`, literal `true` or `false` (without double quotes) is `Bool` and `null` is `nil` (optional type). And remember you have to create **all** instances of custom structs this way.