# How to fetch JSON API using swiftUI if the response received are inside two different arrays?

Tags: json, swift

Aim: To show the API data into Tab bar using SwiftUI

What i tried : I tried to implement the API using model and implemented it into tab view.

What is the issue: i have tried to change my model many time, still the data is not correctly fetched.

Getting error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

API url: https://dev.myhss.org.uk/api/v1/events/eventlist

Optional parameter(can be used):
key : event_type
value: 1(1- upcoming events, 2- past events)

body: x-www-form-unlencoded

Ideal response:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Event Listing",
    "data": {
        "upcoming": [
            {
                "event_id": "1",
                "event_title": "event tile",
                "event_start_date": "2024-02-02 16:55:08",
                "event_end_date": "2024-06-20 16:55:08",
                "event_img": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-1.png",
                "event_chargable_or_not": "0"
            }
        ],
        "past": [
            {
                "event_id": "2",
                "event_title": "event title 2",
                "event_start_date": "2023-04-15 16:55:08",
                "event_end_date": "2023-05-31 16:55:08",
                "event_img": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2.png",
                "event_chargable_or_not": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Updated the suggested code from the answer , but still, the issue persist,
Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

SwiftUI code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventListing: Codable {
    var status: Bool
    var message: String
    var data: Event2
    
}
struct Event2: Codable {
    var upcoming: [Event]
    var past: [Event]
    
}

struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String // Add this property to conform to Identifiable
    var title: String
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date
    var imageURL: URL?
    var isChargeable: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "event_id"
        case title = "event_title"
        case startDate = "event_start_date"
        case endDate = "event_end_date"
        case imageURL = "event_img"
        case isChargeable = "event_chargable_or_not"
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct OkView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            UpcomingEventsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle")
                    Text("Upcoming")
                }
            PastEventsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle.fill")
                    Text("Past")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct UpcomingEventsView: View {
    @State private var events: [Event] = []

    var body: some View {
        List(events) { event in
            Text(event.title)
        }
        .onAppear {
            ApiService.fetchEvents(type: .upcoming) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let eventListing):
                    self.events = eventListing.data.upcoming
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PastEventsView: View {
    @State private var events: [Event] = []

    var body: some View {
        List(events) { event in
            Text(event.title)
        }
        .onAppear {
            ApiService.fetchEvents(type: .past) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let eventListing):
                    self.events = eventListing.data.past
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum EventType {
    case upcoming
    case past
}

class ApiService {
    static let baseUrl = "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/api/v1/events/eventlist"
    static let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    static func fetchEvents(type: EventType, completion: @escaping (Result<EventListing, Error>) -> Void) {
        let endpoint = type == .upcoming ? "events/upcoming" : "events/past"
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseUrl)/\(endpoint)") else {
            completion(.failure(ApiError.invalidUrl))
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(ApiError.noData))
                return
            }
            do {
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
                let eventListing = try decoder.decode(EventListing.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(eventListing))
            } catch let error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    enum ApiError: Error {
        case invalidUrl
        case noData
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with your php service. It returns a `405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: You need decode the json response from the top level, you can't start one level down. So add one struct that contains the `data` key and use that type when decoding. Also, when printing a decoding error use `print(error)` to get a more detailed message than when using `.localizedDescription`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110124/decode-json-data-using-jsondecoder-and-alamofire/52110436#52110436

Comment: Don't add your attempts to solve this to your question, it makes it much harder to understand the question (specially when you remove the original content). If an answer doesn't work then add your feedback to that answer. And also take some time to read the comments people have given.

Comment: if you put you url, `https://dev.myhss.org.uk/api/v1/events/eventlist/events/upcoming` or with `past`
 into your browser, you can see you are not getting what you expect. That is why you get the error. Put `print("--> response: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` just before `do{...}` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, using a `URLRequest` with a `POST` header, instead of your url, and
modified `Event` model, note especially, the `var isChargeable: String?` not `Bool`, works for me.

In addition, you need to consult the server docs, to determine which properties are optional, and adjust the code (add `?`) accordingly.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        OkView()
    }
}

struct OkView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            UpcomingEventsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle")
                    Text("Upcoming")
                }
            PastEventsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle.fill")
                    Text("Past")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct UpcomingEventsView: View {
    @State private var events: [Event] = []

    var body: some View {
        List(events) { event in
            Text(event.title)
        }
        .onAppear {
            ApiService.fetchEvents(type: .upcoming) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let eventListing):
                    self.events = eventListing.data.upcoming
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PastEventsView: View {
    @State private var events: [Event] = []

    var body: some View {
        List(events) { event in
            Text(event.title)
        }
        .onAppear {
            ApiService.fetchEvents(type: .past) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let eventListing):
                    self.events = eventListing.data.past
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum EventType {
    case upcoming
    case past
}

class ApiService {
    static let baseUrl = "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/api/v1/events/eventlist"
    static let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    static func fetchEvents(type: EventType, completion: @escaping (Result<EventListing, Error>) -> Void) {

        let eventType = type == .upcoming ? "1" : "0" // <--- here

        // --- here
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
            completion(.failure(ApiError.invalidUrl))
            return
        }
        
        // --- here
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpBody = "event_type=\(eventType)".data(using: .utf8)!  // <--- here
 
        // --- here (with: request)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(ApiError.noData))
                return
            }
    //        print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")
            do {
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
                let eventListing = try decoder.decode(EventListing.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(eventListing))
            } catch let error {
                print("\n----> decoding error: \(error) \n")
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    enum ApiError: Error {
        case invalidUrl
        case noData
    }
}

struct EventListing: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let upcoming: [Event]
    let past: [Event]
}

struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String // Add this property to conform to Identifiable
    var title: String
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date
    var imageURL: URL?
    var isChargeable: String?  // <--- here
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "event_id"
        case title = "event_title"
        case startDate = "event_start_date"
        case endDate = "event_end_date"
        case imageURL = "event_img"
        case isChargeable = "event_chargable_or_not"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your DTO as

```
 struct EventListing: Codable {
    var status: Bool
    var message: String
    var data: Event2
    
}
struct Event2: Codable {
    var upcoming: [Event]
    var past: [Event]
    
}

struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String // Add this property to conform to Identifiable
    var title: String
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date
    var imageURL: URL?
    var isChargeable: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "event_id"
        case title = "event_title"
        case startDate = "event_start_date"
        case endDate = "event_end_date"
        case imageURL = "event_img"
        case isChargeable = "event_chargable_or_not"
    }
}
```

in your codes i can not see the data part but that should be like these. After change code please check the url is correct and data is coming correctly.