# API structure changed to only objects instead of arrays. Correct way to fetch data using "current_page" & "timeline" parameters?

Tags: json, swift, api

**Aim:** To show the API data into Tab bar using SwiftUI

**What I tried** : I tried to implement the API using model and implemented it into tab view. But unfortunately the API structure got drastically changed and everything got messy.

Code used to fetch API data (updated the details* 2nd time):

```js
import SwiftUI
struct Event: Codable {
    let eventId: String
    let eventTitle: String
    let eventStartDate: String
    let eventEndDate: String
    let eventImg: String
}

enum Timeline: Int {
    case upcoming = 1
    case past = 2
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var events: [Event] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    List(events, id: \.eventId) { event in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(event.eventTitle)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(event.eventStartDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Text(event.eventEndDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            if let url = URL(string: event.eventImg), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: data)!)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Upcoming Events")
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.plus")
                Text("Upcoming")
            }
            .onAppear {
                fetchEvents(timeline: .upcoming, page: 1)
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    List(events, id: \.eventId) { event in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(event.eventTitle)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(event.eventStartDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Text(event.eventEndDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            if let url = URL(string: event.eventImg), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: data)!)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Past Events")
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.minus")
                Text("Past")
            }
            .onAppear {
                fetchEvents(timeline: .upcoming, page: 1)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchEvents(timeline: Timeline, page: Int) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/api/v1/events/eventlist")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let body = "timeline=\(timeline.rawValue)&current_page=\(page)"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, let events = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: [Event]].self, from: data) else {
                print("Error fetching events: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.events = events[timeline == .upcoming ? "upcoming" : "past"] ?? []
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

**Implemented (existing code)**: This is what was implemented but sudden drastic change:

[How to fetch JSON API using swiftUI if the response received are inside two different arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76053943/how-to-fetch-json-api-using-swiftui-if-the-response-received-are-inside-two-diff/76056044#76056044)

**What is the issue:** I have tried to change my model many times, still the data is not correctly fetched.
Getting error in log:

"Error fetching events: Unknown error"

*API url*: https://dev.myhss.org.uk/api/v1/events/eventlist

**parameter**: (key : value)

**timeline**: 1(1- upcoming events, 2- past events)

**current_page**: 1( 1 for 1st page, 2 for second page and so on)

**body**: x-www-form-unlencoded or form data

Response is an example to fetch data for upcoming events only. when timeline value if 2, past events will be shown

**Ideal response:**

```json
    {
        "status": true,
        "message": "Event Listing",
        "data": {
            "upcoming": {
                "0": {
                    "event_id": "5",
                    "event_title": "event title 5",
                    "event_short_description": "short desc 5",
                    "event_detailed_description": "details description 2",
                    "event_start_date": "2025-05-15 16:58:56",
                    "event_end_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "event_mode": "0",
                    "event_level": "0",
                    "event_level_details": null,
                    "event_for_karyakartas_only": "1",
                    "event_for_which_karyakartas": null,
                    "event_attendee_karyakarta_roles": null,
                    "event_attendee_gender": "M",
                    "event_age_category": null,
                    "event_reg_part_time_allowed": null,
                    "event_reg_guest_allowed": null,
                    "event_chargable_or_not": null,
                    "event_capacity": null,
                    "event_waiting_list_allowed": null,
                    "event_wait_list_capacity": null,
                    "event_contact": "<span>Chintu Parekh</span>\r\n<br> <span>info@myhss.org</span>\r\n<p>01255 9875585</p>",
                    "event_notes": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 55 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor",
                    "event_additional_info_required": null,
                    "event_img": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2.png",
                    "event_img_detail": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2-detail.png",
                    "event_created_date": "2025-05-10 16:55:08",
                    "event_created_by": null,
                    "event_online_details": null,
                    "offline_address_id": null,
                    "building_name": "",
                    "address_line_1": "",
                    "address_line_2": "",
                    "city": null,
                    "county": null,
                    "postal_code": "",
                    "country": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null
                },
                "1": {
                    "event_id": "10",
                    "event_title": "event title 10",
                    "event_short_description": "short desc 10",
                    "event_detailed_description": "details description 2",
                    "event_start_date": "2025-05-15 16:58:56",
                    "event_end_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "event_mode": "0",
                    "event_level": "0",
                    "event_level_details": null,
                    "event_for_karyakartas_only": "1",
                    "event_for_which_karyakartas": null,
                    "event_attendee_karyakarta_roles": null,
                    "event_attendee_gender": "M",
                    "event_age_category": null,
                    "event_reg_part_time_allowed": null,
                    "event_reg_guest_allowed": null,
                    "event_chargable_or_not": null,
                    "event_capacity": null,
                    "event_waiting_list_allowed": null,
                    "event_wait_list_capacity": null,
                    "event_contact": "<span>Chintu Parekh</span>\r\n<br> <span>info@myhss.org</span>\r\n<p>01255 9875585</p>",
                    "event_notes": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 55 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor",
                    "event_additional_info_required": null,
                    "event_img": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2.png",
                    "event_img_detail": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2-detail.png",
                    "event_created_date": "2025-05-10 16:55:08",
                    "event_created_by": null,
                    "event_online_details": null,
                    "offline_address_id": null,
                    "building_name": "",
                    "address_line_1": "",
                    "address_line_2": "",
                    "city": null,
                    "county": null,
                    "postal_code": "",
                    "country": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null
                },
                "2": {
                    "event_id": "2",
                    "event_title": "event title 2",
                    "event_short_description": "short desc 2",
                    "event_detailed_description": "details description 2",
                    "event_start_date": "2024-04-15 16:58:56",
                    "event_end_date": "2023-05-31 16:55:08",
                    "event_mode": "0",
                    "event_level": "0",
                    "event_level_details": null,
                    "event_for_karyakartas_only": "1",
                    "event_for_which_karyakartas": null,
                    "event_attendee_karyakarta_roles": null,
                    "event_attendee_gender": "M",
                    "event_age_category": null,
                    "event_reg_part_time_allowed": null,
                    "event_reg_guest_allowed": null,
                    "event_chargable_or_not": null,
                    "event_capacity": null,
                    "event_waiting_list_allowed": null,
                    "event_wait_list_capacity": null,
                    "event_contact": "<span>Chintu Parekh</span>\r\n<br> <span>info@myhss.org</span>\r\n<p>01253 9875485</p>",
                    "event_notes": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor",
                    "event_additional_info_required": null,
                    "event_img": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2.png",
                    "event_img_detail": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2-detail.png",
                    "event_created_date": "2023-04-10 16:55:08",
                    "event_created_by": null,
                    "event_online_details": "http://netflix-events.com",
                    "offline_address_id": "7",
                    "building_name": "",
                    "address_line_1": "Talbot Primary School",
                    "address_line_2": "East Moor Road",
                    "city": "Leeds",
                    "county": "Leeds",
                    "postal_code": "LS8 1AF",
                    "country": "United Kingdom",
                    "latitude": "53.842083",
                    "longitude": "-1.51691735"
                },
                "3": {
                    "event_id": "7",
                    "event_title": "event title 7",
                    "event_short_description": "short desc 7",
                    "event_detailed_description": "details description 2",
                    "event_start_date": "2024-04-15 16:58:56",
                    "event_end_date": "2023-05-31 16:55:08",
                    "event_mode": "0",
                    "event_level": "0",
                    "event_level_details": null,
                    "event_for_karyakartas_only": "1",
                    "event_for_which_karyakartas": null,
                    "event_attendee_karyakarta_roles": null,
                    "event_attendee_gender": "M",
                    "event_age_category": null,
                    "event_reg_part_time_allowed": null,
                    "event_reg_guest_allowed": null,
                    "event_chargable_or_not": null,
                    "event_capacity": null,
                    "event_waiting_list_allowed": null,
                    "event_wait_list_capacity": null,
                    "event_contact": "<span>Chintu Parekh</span>\r\n<br> <span>info@myhss.org</span>\r\n<p>01253 9875485</p>",
                    "event_notes": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor",
                    "event_additional_info_required": null,
                    "event_img": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2.png",
                    "event_img_detail": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2-detail.png",
                    "event_created_date": "2023-04-10 16:55:08",
                    "event_created_by": null,
                    "event_online_details": null,
                    "offline_address_id": null,
                    "building_name": "",
                    "address_line_1": "",
                    "address_line_2": "",
                    "city": null,
                    "county": null,
                    "postal_code": "",
                    "country": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null
                },
                "4": {
                    "event_id": "8",
                    "event_title": "event title 8",
                    "event_short_description": "short desc 8",
                    "event_detailed_description": "details description 2",
                    "event_start_date": "2024-04-15 16:58:56",
                    "event_end_date": "2023-05-31 16:55:08",
                    "event_mode": "0",
                    "event_level": "0",
                    "event_level_details": null,
                    "event_for_karyakartas_only": "1",
                    "event_for_which_karyakartas": null,
                    "event_attendee_karyakarta_roles": null,
                    "event_attendee_gender": "M",
                    "event_age_category": null,
                    "event_reg_part_time_allowed": null,
                    "event_reg_guest_allowed": null,
                    "event_chargable_or_not": null,
                    "event_capacity": null,
                    "event_waiting_list_allowed": null,
                    "event_wait_list_capacity": null,
                    "event_contact": "<span>Chintu Parekh</span>\r\n<br> <span>info@myhss.org</span>\r\n<p>01253 9875485</p>",
                    "event_notes": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor",
                    "event_additional_info_required": null,
                    "event_img": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2.png",
                    "event_img_detail": "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/assets/events/event-2-detail.png",
                    "event_created_date": "2023-04-10 16:55:08",
                    "event_created_by": null,
                    "event_online_details": null,
                    "offline_address_id": null,
                    "building_name": "",
                    "address_line_1": "",
                    "address_line_2": "",
                    "city": null,
                    "county": null,
                    "postal_code": "",
                    "country": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null
                },
                "total_pages": 2,
                "current_page": 1,
                "per_page": 5,
                "pagination_links": "",
                "next": 2,
                "previous": 0,
                "total_records": 8
            },
            "past": {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can paste your json here and it will generate the model code for you: https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76053943/how-to-fetch-json-api-using-swiftui-if-the-response-received-are-inside-two-diff/76056044#76056044
 
 use `print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")` as shown in the answer code.
You will see that the json data you get from the server, is not what you show in this question.
That is the reason you get the decoding error you show. Show your code for the `URLRequest` you are using.

Comment: ok. i have now added the code i'm using to get the data for API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code `... to correctly fetch API data smoothly when the API structure is completely changed?`
Pay attention to all the details. It uses a dynamic key (AnyKey) to fetch the upcoming and past data
into an array of events. What is left for you todo, is to download the images separatly, without
using the `try? Data(contentsOf: url)`, use the regular `URLSession` or `AsyncImage` as shown.

Note, you still need to consult the API docs, to determine which properties are optional, then add `?` to those.

The important part in the code is to use the `do/try/catch` pattern, with a `print(error)` in the `catch`. Without this, you will keep struggling to find the reasons for your errors.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}

enum Timeline: Int {
    case upcoming = 1
    case past = 2
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var events: [Event] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    List(events) { event in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(event.eventTitle)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(event.eventStartDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Text(event.eventEndDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: event.eventImg)) { image in
                              image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                            } placeholder: { ProgressView() }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Upcoming Events")
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.plus")
                Text("Upcoming")
            }
            .onAppear {
                fetchEvents(timeline: .upcoming, page: 1)
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    List(events) { event in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(event.eventTitle)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(event.eventStartDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Text(event.eventEndDate)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: event.eventImg)) { image in
                              image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                            } placeholder: { ProgressView() }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Past Events")
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.minus")
                Text("Past")
            }
            .onAppear {
                fetchEvents(timeline: .past, page: 1)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchEvents(timeline: Timeline, page: Int) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://dev.myhss.org.uk/api/v1/events/eventlist")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let body = "timeline=\(timeline.rawValue)&current_page=\(page)"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Error fetching events: \(error)") // <-- here
                return
            }
            //  print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")
            do {
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(EventListing.self, from: data)
                //  print("\n----> results: \(results) \n")
                self.events = timeline == .upcoming ? results.data.upcoming.events : results.data.past.events
            } catch let error {
                print("\n----> decoding error: \(error) \n") // <-- here important
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}

struct EventListing: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: DataClass
}

struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    let eventID, eventTitle, eventShortDescription, eventDetailedDescription: String
    let eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventMode, eventLevel: String
    let eventLevelDetails: String?
    let eventForKaryakartasOnly: String
    let eventForWhichKaryakartas, eventAttendeeKaryakartaRoles: String?
    let eventAttendeeGender: String
    let eventAgeCategory, eventRegPartTimeAllowed, eventRegGuestAllowed, eventChargableOrNot: String?
    let eventCapacity, eventWaitingListAllowed, eventWaitListCapacity: String?
    let eventContact, eventNotes: String
    let eventAdditionalInfoRequired: String?
    let eventImg, eventImgDetail: String
    let eventCreatedDate: String
    let eventCreatedBy: String?
    let status: String
    let eventOnlineDetails, offlineAddressID: String?
    let buildingName, addressLine1, addressLine2: String
    let city, county: String?
    let postalCode: String
    let country, latitude, longitude: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case country, latitude, longitude, status, city, county
        case eventID = "event_id"
        case eventTitle = "event_title"
        case eventShortDescription = "event_short_description"
        case eventDetailedDescription = "event_detailed_description"
        case eventStartDate = "event_start_date"
        case eventEndDate = "event_end_date"
        case eventMode = "event_mode"
        case eventLevel = "event_level"
        case eventLevelDetails = "event_level_details"
        case eventForKaryakartasOnly = "event_for_karyakartas_only"
        case eventForWhichKaryakartas = "event_for_which_karyakartas"
        case eventAttendeeKaryakartaRoles = "event_attendee_karyakarta_roles"
        case eventAttendeeGender = "event_attendee_gender"
        case eventAgeCategory = "event_age_category"
        case eventRegPartTimeAllowed = "event_reg_part_time_allowed"
        case eventRegGuestAllowed = "event_reg_guest_allowed"
        case eventChargableOrNot = "event_chargable_or_not"
        case eventCapacity = "event_capacity"
        case eventWaitingListAllowed = "event_waiting_list_allowed"
        case eventWaitListCapacity = "event_wait_list_capacity"
        case eventContact = "event_contact"
        case eventNotes = "event_notes"
        case eventAdditionalInfoRequired = "event_additional_info_required"
        case eventImg = "event_img"
        case eventImgDetail = "event_img_detail"
        case eventCreatedDate = "event_created_date"
        case eventCreatedBy = "event_created_by"
        case eventOnlineDetails = "event_online_details"
        case offlineAddressID = "offline_address_id"
        case buildingName = "building_name"
        case addressLine1 = "address_line_1"
        case addressLine2 = "address_line_2"
        case postalCode = "postal_code"
    }
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let upcoming: EventDatum
    let past: EventDatum
}

struct EventDatum: Codable {
    var events: [Event]
    let totalPages, currentPage, perPage: Int?
    let paginationLinks: String?
    let next, previous, totalRecords: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case next, previous
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case currentPage = "current_page"
        case perPage = "per_page"
        case paginationLinks = "pagination_links"
        case totalRecords = "total_records"
    }
    
    struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?
        
        init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        totalPages = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .totalPages)
        currentPage = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .currentPage)
        perPage = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .perPage)
        next = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .next)
        previous = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .previous)
        totalRecords = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .totalRecords)
        paginationLinks = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .paginationLinks)
        events = []
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
        container.allKeys.forEach { key in
            if let results = try? container.decode(Event.self, forKey: key) {
                self.events.append(results)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tested, working smooth . Thanks